# ASP.NET 4.0 URL Routing - Similar MapPageRoutes

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, url-routing

I will try to explain this the best I can.

I created a CMS that allows you to create Categories and Content Sections. Both have completely different templates, but I want to use the same URL routing mapPageRoute param when routing. Basically, I need it to check if the alias is a category, if not hit the content section router.

Here is my Registered Routes on Global.asax:

```
void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute(
        "Home",
        string.Empty,
        "~/Default.aspx"
    );

    routes.MapPageRoute(
        "Category",
        "{*CategoryAlias}",
        "~/templates/Category.aspx"
    );

    routes.MapPageRoute(
        "Content",
        "{*ContentAlias}",
        "~/templates/Content.aspx"
    );
}
```

Currently, Categories work fine, but when I put a content section alias in the URL it hits categories and doesn't skip to the next route to try. The Category.aspx and Content.aspx web forms have completely different views. The code behind is similar but one accesses the Category tables/procedures and the other Content.

If anyone requires more information just ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) 
{ 
    routes.MapPageRoute( 
        "Home", 
        string.Empty, 
        "~/Default.aspx" 
    ); 

    routes.MapPageRoute( 
        "Category", 
        "Category/{Cat}/{*queryvalues}", 
        "~/templates/Category.aspx" 
    ); 

    routes.MapPageRoute( 
        "Content", 
        "Content/{Cont}{*queryvalues}", 
        "~/templates/Content.aspx" 
    ); 
}
```

And then make sure the URLs have either Category or Content in the path.  You still get the catch-all with `*queryvalues`

EDIT:

If you have the following uri `http://www.example.com/Content/Press` you can access `Press` by using the following:

```
Page.RouteData.Values["Cont"].ToString();
```

So, in your Content.aspx page, grab that string and then use that to determine which site the user was trying to get to.

You need to include some kind of static URL differentiator so that the MapRouter can find where to map the page.

If you don't include the static `Category` or `Content` in the beginning of the uri, the MapRouter will always be satisfied with the first map (the Category mapping) and never know to skip it.

Comment: Yeah that's the thing, i don't want there to be an extra param in the URL. I want it to be www.website.com/category or www.webiste.com/content

Comment: The *queryvalues are a catch all. Those route maps catch www.website.com/Category or www.webiste.com/Content as well as www.website.com/Category/foo or www.webiste.com/Content/foo/bar?m=rand

Comment: Say I have a Content Section called "Press" and a Category called "News" If the URLs are www.website.com/Press or www.website.com/News will it know to switch to the latter template if the first one is false?

Comment: I edited my post.  Basically, you need a way to prove that the first mapping is false in order to skip to the second one.  If you don't have some kind of static content, the MapRouter will never fail to route with the first Map you add.

Comment: What you have above I understand but the links will still have /category or /content within the URL and i don't want that at all. I do need to figure out a way to check against both...

Comment: Hmmm... Idk if that can be done with ASP.net.  Have you looked into MVC?  The Routing with MVC is much more powerful.  You can create an object that inherits from `IRouteConstraint` and put some logic into your routing.  If you want an example for WCF, let me know and I'll post one

Comment: I found a work around for it. I just ended up using one of the routes. I don't think it can be done and I will eventually be moving to MVC 4. Thanks though, I'll mark this has correct as its the only option

Comment: Thanks! Good choice in moving to MVC. Good luck

Comment: @joe_coolish It is not possible in asp.net basic web form application? I have similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38393051/define-multiple-routing-in-global-asax-not-working?noredirect=1#comment64195204_38393051

Comment: @balexander It is not possible in asp.net basic web form application? I have similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38393051/define-multiple-routing-in-global-asax-not-working?noredirect=1#comment64195204_38393051

Comment: I haven't worked with ASP.NET Web Forms in YEARS.  I don't know much about routing with respect to web forms, sorry.  Have you thought about converting your app to MVC?