# Routing or similar in asp.net webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my web application, each user has a profile page. I want this profile page accessable by typing www.nameofwebsite.com/username

Is this possible in a webforms solution? if so, please tell me how :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible

you can do using System.Web.Routing name space

RouteCollection MapPageRoute

[Refer this](https://deepumi.wordpress.com/2010/05/14/asp-net-4-0-url-routing/)

or  can follow

[Route Asp.net Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663616/asp-net-4-0-url-routing-similar-mappageroutes)