# unwanted html form action using URL Routing in ASP.NET 4 Web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, url-routing

I have a working ASP.NET 4 Web Forms site, but now I need to apply url routing

I have on my global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute(
               "Route1",               
               "Page/{P1}/{P2}/{P3}/{P4}",  
               "~/Page.aspx"
            );
}
```

It's mapping fine my route, but the resulting html form has a wrong action attribute, which consists on the value of the url param {P4}

Writting in Page_Load

```
Form.Action = Request.RawUrl;
```

doesn't work neither. But it's working fine if I write the actual url:

```
Form.Action = "Page.aspx?params...";
```

I hope you could help

Comment: take a look at the following link and see if this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663616/asp-net-4-0-url-routing-similar-mappageroutes

Comment: I didn't explain myself very well, my problem is, for example: for the url "Page/abc/123/bcd/456", the html form is builded like this <form action="456">